# conditional date query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to structure a query which returns data which if `priority = emergency` is in the last 2 weeks, and if `urgent` is in the last month.

```
WHERE ((priority = 'emergency' and date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)) or
priority = 'urgent' and date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
```

I know this isn't right, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just looks like your parentheses are in the wrong place:

```
WHERE ( priority = 'emergency' and date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) ) 
   OR ( priority = 'urgent' and date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) )
```

Since not all months are 30 days you might have to adjust the interval if you want strictly one month back.